# How to calculate total and draw chart of an Aggression

Tags: histogram, tableau-api

I've a table:

```
ID   No. of IA    Timeline
001  1            after
001  1            after
001  1            after
002  1            after
002  1            after
003  1            after
003  1            after
003  1            after
003  1            after
004  0            after
005  1            after
005  1            after
```

When I placed in in Tableau I get:

[image]

What I want to do is to use `Agg(Total Cou...` and make a histogram.
[image]

but since I've and Aggregation value I'm unable to do that or find a solution even in Tableau official forums.

Comment: I think you mean Aggregation instead of Aggression — but it sometimes seems the other way around :-).

Comment: Read about LOD calcs. That feature may do what you want

Comment: Since you are trying to create histogram. Create a bin using the column you want to

Comment: @AlexBlakemore yes it's Aggregation :D Thanks for the LOD suggestion I'll look into it.